# NSURL connection for objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

I have created a page for my app where the top 10 user profile will be displayed along with their name, age, city and distance. Currently my page looks like this

[image: current page]

**and I have to display like this**

[image: page need to be like this]

For this I've asked to use POST method.where path, name, age,city and distance need to be displayed.

Can anyone please suggest me how to hit web service as I've no idea about the NSURL connection.Kindly help!!

Comment: what you have tried ?. First search on SO. You will get so many answers. If you didnt get any, then post your question.

Comment: add google to your friend list :) ... https://www.google.co.in/search?q=call+webservice+ios&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=EgtxV6q-ApDT8gfBm46QDg#q=call+webservice+ios+objc

Comment: refer this - http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/

Comment: Just follow this link for basic. https://yuvarajmanickam.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/nsurlconnection-basics-for-ios-beginners/

Comment: thanks Ekta Mam!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
This code may be help you
Add NSURLConnectionDelegate delegate
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController<NSURLConnectionDelegate>

And some where in function in same interface
// Send a synchronous request
NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];

NSURLResponse * response = nil;

NSError * error = nil;

NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                          returningResponse:&response
                                                      error:&error]; 

if (error == nil) {
    // Parse data here
}
And for more this link help you 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html
```

Comment: `sendSynchronousRequest` is deprecated and Apple strongly discourages from using synchronous networking anyway.

Answer (score 0):

- Import `AFNetworking 3.0` to your project and try the following:

  ```
  NSString *urlString  = @"https://www.example.com/info

  NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  //add parameters to dictionary

  AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

  [manager POST:urlString parameters:parameters progress:nil 
  success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {


          NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);//you have to parse this object

      } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

  }];
  ```